# Unexpected failure of custom registered Reverter using TJSONUnMarshal

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

The code below is from the JSonMarshall project in chapter 7 of Marco Cantu's Delphi 2010 Handbook.  The source code is available from here http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/27600.  I have made two changes to it:

1. Add JSon to the implementation Uses clause to get it to compile.
2. Added the line

   theName := 'XXX';  // added by me

to the `TDataWithList.Create` constructor to assist debugging

I am running the code in Delphi Seattle (without update 1)

The purpose of the project is to demo a custom converter and reverter for the TDataWithList declared type.  The custom converter seems to work fine, judging by the result output to `Memo1`.

However, attempting to run the reverter results in a "Read of address 00000000" AV on the line

```
           sList.Add (Args[I]);
```

in `btnUnmarshalReverterClick`.  The immediate cause of this is that contrary to what
the author evidently intended, when the above line executes, sList is Nil.

My question is simply why is sList Nil and how to fix this problem?

I have tried, not entirely successfully, to trace through the DBXJSONReflect source
to find out why.

After

```
  Obj := ObjectInstance(FRTTICtx, objType);
```

in function `TJSONUnMarshal.CreateObject`, TDataWithList(obj).theName is 'XXX'
as I'd expect and TDataWithList(obj).theLList is an initialized, but empty,
TStringList.

However, by the time the anonymous method in `btnUnmarshalReverterClick` is called, TDataWithList(Data).theList is `Nil`.

**Update:**  The reason that TDataWithList(Data).theList (incorrectly, imo) becomes Nil is that it is set to Nil in TJSONPopulationCustomizer.PrePopulate by a call to PrePopulateObjField.  So I suppose the question is, why does PrePopulate allow an object's field which has been initialized in its constructor to be overwritten as if it knows better that the object's constructor.

**Update2:**

There may be an additional problem, in that as far as I can tell, in
`TInternalJSONPopulationCustomizer.PrePopulateObjField`, the assignment which overwrites TListWithData.theList with Nil, namely

```
rttiField.SetValue(Data, TValue.Empty);
```

does not seem to result in the TStringlist destructor being called.

Btw, I get the same error running the project in XE4, which is the earliest version I have which includes JSonUnMarshal.

Code:

```
type
  [...]

  TDataWithList = class
  private
    theName: String;
    theList: TStringList;
  public
    constructor Create (const aName: string); overload;
    constructor Create; overload;
    function ToString: string; override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

[...]

procedure TFormJson.btnMarshalConverterClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  theData: TDataWithList;
  jMarshal: TJSONMarshal;
  jValue: TJSONValue;
begin
  theData := TDataWithList.Create('john');
  try
    jMarshal := TJSONMarshal.Create(
      TJSONConverter.Create); // converter is owned
    try
      jMarshal.RegisterConverter(TDataWithList, 'theList',
        function (Data: TObject; Field: string): TListOfStrings
        var
          I: Integer;
          sList: TStringList;
        begin
          sList := TDataWithList(Data).theList;
          SetLength(Result, sList.Count);
          for I := 0 to sList.Count - 1 do
            Result[I] := sList[I];
        end);
      jValue := jMarshal.Marshal(theData);
      try
        Memo1.Lines.Text := jValue.ToString;
      finally
        jValue.Free;
      end;
    finally
      jMarshal.Free;
    end;
  finally
    theData.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TFormJson.btnUnmarshalReverterClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  jUnmarshal: TJSONUnMarshal;
  jValue: TJSONValue;
  anObject: TObject;
begin
  jValue := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(
    TEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes (Memo1.Lines.Text), 0);
  try
    jUnmarshal := TJSONUnMarshal.Create;
    try
      jUnmarshal.RegisterReverter(TDataWithList, 'theList',
        procedure (Data: TObject; Field: string; Args: TListOfStrings)
        var
          I: Integer;
          sList: TStringList;
        begin
          sList := TDataWithList(Data).theList;
          for I := 0 to Length(Args) - 1 do
             sList.Add (Args[I]);
        end);
      anObject := jUnmarshal.Unmarshal(jValue);
      try
        ShowMessage ('Class: ' + anObject.ClassName +
          sLineBreak + anObject.ToString);
      finally
        anObject.Free;
      end;
    finally
      jUnmarshal.Free;
    end;
  finally
    jValue.Free;
  end;
end;

function TMyData.ToString: string;
begin
  Result := theName + ':' + IntToStr (theValue);
end;

{ TDataWithList }

constructor TDataWithList.Create(const aName: string);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  theName := aName;
  theList := TStringList.Create;
  for I := 0 to 9 do
    theList.Add(IntToStr (Random (1000)));
end;

constructor TDataWithList.Create;
begin
  // core initialization, used for default construction
  theName := 'XXX';  // added by me
  theList := TStringList.Create;
end;

destructor TDataWithList.Destroy;
begin
  theList.Free;
  inherited;
end;

function TDataWithList.ToString: string;
begin
  Result := theName + sLineBreak + theList.Text;
end;
```

Comment: Would a [mcve] be possible? Then we don't have to spend time trying to make it ourself.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan:  Hmm, problem is, I'm finding the code in DBXJSONReflect pretty impenetrable, so am not sure I could boil the problem down w/o losing the essence of it.  In particular, I can see no sign of the logic which led its implementors to think that they could overwrite a constructor-initialized object field willy nilly with Nil in the first place. Marco's demo is fairly minimal, fwiw, and the bits I've quoted are about the shortest code I could imagine manifesting the problem.

Comment: @David: I'll see if I can disentangle sufficient of the innards of DBXJSONReflect to make something smaller.

Answer (score 3):

`rttiField.SetValue(Data, TValue.Empty);` simply overrides the field value because as the name implies it's a field, not a property with get / set methods. The destructor of TStringList is not called due to simple pointer assignment.

The solution here is to declare a property:

```
TDataWithList = class
  ...
  strict private
    theList: TStringList;
    ...
  public
    property Data: TStringList read ... write SetData
    ...
end;

TDataWithList.SetData(TStringList aValue);
begin
  theList.Assign(aValue);
end;
```

Comment: Interesting.  I tried this and the reverter now seems to work, but I'm getting a $C0000005 exception "Access violations at 0x00000000 read of address 0x00000000 followed by a report of two unexpected small-block memory leaks, referring to TMCSEncoding x1 and TUTF8Encoding x 1.  Let me look a bit into that, meanwhile +1, thanks.

Comment: Well, the AV on shutdown is being caused by the FAnsiEncoding of TEncoding getting corrupted during the call to TJSONUnMarshal.PopulateFields.  It happens when TJSONUnMarshal.ClassTypeOf is called for the FDelimiter field of the TStringlist, specifically when the statement fRtti := tRtti.GetField(Field) is executed.  Atm I have absolutely no idea why calling tRtti.GetField should cause this, but it does.

Comment: @MartynA Why is there even code that processes fields instead of properties? That is dangerous at best. Can't you disable this behavior?

Comment: Don't ask me, it's Marco Cantu's code in the demo, and he's better placed to know what he's doing than I am, and all the rest is in Delphi's r/t libraries.  With your change, as I said, the reverter does what it's supposed to do, but it causes corruption of the TEncoding class object that causes the AV on shutdown.

Comment: @MartynA Ok, then how about using a simple `array of string` aka `TListOfStrings` instead of `TStringList`? I think this issue is just a bug that needs to be fixed, so you need to try some workarounds here.

Comment: You may be right that it's "just a bug", but tbh since it's manifestly not one of my own making, there are limits to what I'm prepared to do to track it down.  In any case, if  Delphi's implementation of JSon can't even correctly handle one of Delphi's most basic inherent types, what does that say about EMBA's levels of testing, and why should we do their work for them?

Comment: EMBA is known for having a strange testing and support policy, i dunno how long you are in the Delphi game but all i can say is be prepared for more bugs to come *G*

Comment: Yes, "strange" indeed.  I started with TP3 circa 1985 and have used Delphi since it came out (D1 on OS/2).  Anyway, I was only looking at Marco's demo out of interest & don't need JSon myself  so I won't be holding my breath until anything gets fixed.