# Calling TJSONUnMarshal.Unmarshal on a marshalled TStringlist causes memory corruption?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

This q is to provide an MCVE to illustrate a problem uncovered by the answer to this earlier one of mine:

[Unexpected failure of custom registered Reverter using TJSONUnMarshal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34556774/unexpected-failure-of-custom-registered-reverter-using-tjsonunmarshal)

In my earlier q, the answer from @VirusTrinity fixed the problem I was initially having,
namely that the object obtained by the unmarshalling operation was incorrectly returned
with a Nil TStringlist field.  However, the fix uncovered a new problem, which is that
on shutdown of the application, it generates a 0xC0000005 exception, access violation at
address 0x00000000 read of address 0x00000000.  The code below shows this behaviour, generating
the same AV on shutdown, with the same cause.

The AV evidently occurs due to memory corruption during execution of `PopulateFields(objFields, Obj, customizer);` in `function TJSONUnMarshal.CreateObject(JsonObj: TJSONObject): TObject` in Data.DBXJSONReflect.

If you put a breakpoint where shown below in the code, add a watch on
TEncoding.FAnsiEncoding and then single-step through

```
AnObject:= jUnmarshal.Unmarshal(jValue);
```

you should find that the value in the FMaxCharSize changes from 1 to 5 (sometimes
in the previous q I got 7 instead of 5).  This change seems to be symptomatic of
the memory corruption which apparently causes the AV on shutdown.

**Update:** To see where the AV occurs, place a breakpoint on the entry point to class procedure TEncoding.FreeEncodings.  For me, the AV occurs when

```
FreeAndNil(FANSIEncoding);
```

is called.

**Update #2:** The point where TEncoding.FAnsiEncoding gets corrupted is when `function TJSONUnMarshal.ClassTypeOf` is called with the Field parameter having the value `FDelimiter` and executes the statement

```
    fRtti := tRtti.GetField(Field);
```

The call to `ClassTypeOf` is from the statement

```
    else if HasReverter(ComposeKey(ClassTypeOf(Data, FieldName),
    FIELD_ANY)) then
```

at line 30222/3023 of `procedure TJSONUnMarshal.PopulateFields`

Could anyone confirm the problem and advise why it is occurring?

Code:

```
program MATest;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses Classes, System.SysUtils, JSon, DBXJson, DBXJSONReflect;

procedure Test;
var
  TL1,
  TL2 : TStringlist;
  AnObject : TObject;
  jMarshal: TJSONMarshal;
  jUnMarshal : TJSonUnMarshal;
  jValue: TJSONValue;
begin
  TL1 := TStringlist.Create;
  TL1.Add('AAA');
  try
    jMarshal := TJSONMarshal.Create(TJSONConverter.Create);

    jValue := jMarshal.Marshal(TL1);
    Writeln(jValue.ToString);

    jUnMarshal := TJSONUnMarshal.Create;  //  < Put breakpoint here and
    //  add watch of TEncoding.FAnsiEncoding in System.SysUtils
    AnObject:= jUnMarshal.UnMarshal(jValue);
    TL2 := TStringlist(AnObject);
    Writeln(TL2.Text);
    Readln;

  finally
    jValue.Free;
    jMarshal.Free;
    jUnMarshal.Free;
    TL1.Free;
    TL2.Free;
  end;
end;

begin
  try
    Test;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: I rolled back the edit by A N Other so that it refers to a problem "uncovered by the answer" to the previous q because my change was intentional and accurate - there was nothing wrong with the answer per se, it fixed the problem I'd originally asked about.